# For continuous functions, preimage of open set is open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous function from a metric space $X$ into $Y$. If $V\subset Y$ and $V$ is open, then show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

The proofs I've seen of the fact that open sets have open preimages either use the fact that continuous functions map limit points to limit points, or they use a completely topological proof.

Is there a more basic metric feeling proof? Something that just uses the basic definition of open sets, and the basic definition of continuity? Or are these sequential/topological arguments *the only* arguments to make?

Comment: Actually thats the definition of a continuous function $f$.

Comment: @PenasRaul That is *one* definition of continuity, used in general topology. In metric spaces, the ε–δ style definition is (perhaps) more commonly used. It is, of course, equivalent, but that equivalence is what the question is about, no?

Comment: Bottom of https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/easyanalysis1.html feels metrical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function from a metric space $X$ into $Y$. If $V\subset Y$ and $V$ is open, then we shall prove that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

Suppose that $p\in X$ and $f(p)\in V$. Since $V$ is open, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $y=f(x) \in V$ if $d_{Y}(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$, and since $f$ is continuous at $p$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_{Y}(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$ if $d_{X}(x,p)<\delta$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}{(V)}$ as soon as $d_X(x,p)<\delta$.

Comment: I find the logic in the proof not solid enough: because if e.g. $d_{X}(x,p)\geq\delta$ it is still possible that $d_{Y}(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$.

Comment: That is not an issue. We only need that the membership hold true whenever $d_X(x,p)<\delta$. We do not care what happens otherwise.

Comment: My question though is, what if the domain is not all of $X$? How can we guarantee that $\delta$ can be small enough such that the entire ball around $x$ is contained in the domain?

Comment: @hicrypto123. Not sure if the domain "not all of $X$" matters here. The metric is defined on the domain.

Comment: Great, even though at first I was confused by part  `>0 such that y =() ∈  ...`.  

In that epsilon neighborhood of f(p), _all_ of its elements $z \neq f(p)$ might have a preimage in X, but also just _some_ of them or _none_ (just $f(p)$). The important part is there exists the delta neighborhood around arbitrary $p$ from the preimage that maps into V, more specifically into the neighborhood of $f(p)$, but not necessarily to every its point.

Comment: Who guarantees that $f^{-1}$ exist? $f$ is not injective in general.

Comment: @ric.san $f$ doesn't have to be injective. $f^{-1}$ can be a one-to-many function. The proof still works.