# Prove that the Mandelbrot Set Is A Closed Set

Tags: complex-analysis, chaos-theory, complex-dynamics

The Problem: Suppose we define the Mandelbrot Set as the following

For  $c \in \mathbb{C}$  , $\mathbb{M}$ = $({c:|c| \leq 2}) \cap ({c: |c^2 + c| \leq 2}) \cap ({c: |(c^2+c)^2 + c| \leq 2})       \cap ...$

Carefully argue that each set in this intersection of sets is a closed subset of the Complex Plane. By this, show that the Mandelbrot Set is closed.

The attempt - So for each $i \in \mathbb{N} $, we can write this set as the following:

$\mathbb{M}= (c \in \mathbb{C} : |Q_{c}^{n} (0)| \leq 2)$, for $i \geq 1$,  which $Q_{c} (z) = z^2+c$. Now if we are going to show the set is closed, we can show that the complement of each set is open, which it is for each $i$, $\mathbb{M}^{c}= (c \in \mathbb{C} : |Q_{c}^{n} (0)| > 2)$, for $i \geq 1$.

To show each set is open, we can find an ε-neighborhood of any point, $z_{0} \in \mathbb{M^c}$ for which $N(z_{0}, ε) \subseteq \mathbb{M} ^{c}$.

I can define $ε = max ({2, |z_{0}|})$ and that is all I got so far.

I am not sure if I am on the right track. However, there was a hint to this problem which I do not know what it means (Hint: If $F : \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, is a continuous function, then for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$, 
the set $(c \in \mathbb{C} : F(c) \leq b)$. Is this the neighborhood I was supposed to be defining?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is this your missing link: [For continuous functions, preimage of open set is open.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921189/for-continuous-functions-preimage-of-open-set-is-open) ? From that follows immediately that each $\mathbb{M}^{c}$ is open.

Comment: the intersection of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 9):

Each of your sets has the form
$$ \{ c \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert p(c) \rvert \le 2 \} $$
where $p$ is some *polynomial*.

Now you ought to know that every polynomial is continuous, and that $z\mapsto \lvert z \rvert$ is continuous, and that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

Thus, apply the hint with the function $F(x) = \lvert p(x)\rvert$ and $b=2$ to see that each of your sets are *closed*. Since any (possibly infinite) intersection of closed sets is closed, the conclusion follows.

(And entirely without having to do manual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs yourself. It's all in connecting building blocks you should already have at this point).

Comment: Okay. So hypothetically, if this hint were not to take place, could I possibly use a $ε-δ$  proof as another way to show this is true? Το me, it does sound not that difficult at all to prove that each set is closed.